# domain and range discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Define the relation T on ℝ+ by

T = {(x, y):y=7/2X-5}

(i) State the domain and range of T.

(ii) Is T a function? State your reason.

i)for domain: 2x-5>0 -> x>5/2 (domain of T)

```
          Range: o<y<+infinity
```

ii)Yes, T is a function because each value in domain is only maped to a single value in domain.

this is my ans, can i check if i am right or wrong?

Comment: Assuming you meant $$y = \frac{7}{2x - 5}$$ you are correct.